# How to separate console.log results?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var results = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
    var largestNumber = arr[n][0]; 
    console.log([n])
    for (var sb = 1; sb < arr.length; sb++) {
      if (arr[n][sb] > largestNumber) {
          largestNumber = arr[n][sb];
      }
    } 
    results[n] = largestNumber;

  }

  return results;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

There are two console.log and the result comes as this:

```
0
1
2
3
5,27,39,1001
```

How do I make it come like this:

```
0
1
2
3
____________
5,27,39,1001
```

?

I'm new to javascript so I'm trying to see how arrays work exactly so I need to separate each outcome to figure out how it exactly works!

Comment: `console.log('_________');` ??

Comment: With one more console log :p

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't console.log inside a call to console.log but that's a matter of personal preference.

With minimal change to your code you could change this line

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]))

to this line

console.log('------------------------------------------\n', largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]))